# Xcode Objective-C: Text to speech is always in English even if the iPhone is set to another language

Tags: ios, objective-c, text-to-speech

I have this code to make my app read a text

```
self->myUtterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Ciao come stai?"];
self->myUtterance.rate = 0.5;
self-> myUtterance.pitchMultiplier = 1.5;
//self-> myUtterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"it-IT"];
self->synth = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[self->synth speakUtterance:self->myUtterance];
```

I've read that "By default, AVSpeechSynthesizer will speak using a voice based on the user’s current language preferences." but it does not work.

Indeed even if my iPhone is all set to Italian language and region the voice is in English.

If I remove the comment to this line of code

```
//self-> myUtterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"it-IT"];
```

Then the voice is in Italian but I wish that the language is automatically set based on the user's language preferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] firstObject]` to find the application current language.

(If it's `nil` or if your app is not localized you can use `[[NSLocale currentLocale] languageCode]` instead, but this does not take care of the language specified in the settings, whenever the user changes the language of the app only, not for all the device)

This way you can specify the language with `[AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:]` and be sure you have the app language spoken.

Otherwise you can let the user choose the spoken language.

Comment: I tried to print it out [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] firstObject] in console and I get eng as language even if the iPhone is set to Italian. Do you know if is it normal?

Comment: Does your application support localization for Italian?

Comment: Nope. So in order to make the text to speech speak the language based on the user region it must support the localization for that language?

Comment: That's the idea I'm afraid. Otherwise you can stick with a static value, that may be chosen by your user. Have you tried `[[NSLocale currentLocale] languageCode]` maybe it will help you if your app is not localized.

Comment: I see thanks for the information. I guess I'll let the user choose the language for the text to speech. It seems to be the best option.

Comment: Ok, don't forget to accept my answer I'll edit it with the fact that the app has to be localized.